# Using parameters of a function in another function in C++?

Tags: c++

I have made a simple calculator with c++, I have different functions for doing, add, subtraction, division and multiplication. The problem is **Its not a problem just a code clean up question all my code is running**.So here is my code

```
#include <iostream>

void sum(int a, int b)
{
    int result = a + b;
    std::cout << "The result of sum of " << a << " and " << b << " is: " << "\"" << result << "\"" << std::endl;
}

void subtract(int a, int b)
{
    int result = a - b;
    std::cout << "The result of subtraction of " << a << " and " << b << " is: " << "\"" << result << "\"" << std::endl;
}

void multiply(int a, int b)
{
    int result = a * b;
    std::cout << "The result of multiplication of " << a << " and " << b << " is: " << "\"" <<     result << "\"" << std::endl;
}

void divide(int a, int b)
{
    int result = a / b;
    std::cout << "The result of division of " << a << " and " << b << " is: " << "\"" << result << "\"" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a, b, result;
    char symbol;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "Enter an operator: ";
    std::cin >> symbol;
    std::cout << "Enter another number: ";
    std::cin >> b;
    if (symbol == '+') sum(a, b);
    else if (symbol == '-') subtract(a, b);
    else if (symbol == '*') multiply(a, b);
    else if (symbol == '/') divide(a, b);
    else std::cout << "Invalid Operator. Try using the four fundamental operators +, -, *, /" << std::endl;
    system("pause");
  }
```

here, in each of my functions of add, sub, multiplication & division....`std::cout << "The result of sum of " << a << " and " << b << " is: " << "\"" << result << "\"" <<     std::endl;`
This line is kind of recurring I want to make this line as a function and use the parameters a and b you got it I want my code to be same as is  by making this line another function how do I do it? if I do it in normal way then how will I tell my function about 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: ...why...do...you...use....so...many...dots? Words are separated by spaces, sentences are separated by a full stop and a space. Beginnings of sentences start with a capital letter. Please reformat your post.

Comment: Sorry! I am new and this is my first post. I am learning gradually. I fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: `if I do it in normal way then how will I telly my function about 'a' and 'b'?` The same way you have done with other functions. You define a function, you use it with the arguments you want. I recommend you learning better the basics of functions and methods.

Comment: Of course, I will learn! But why I am getting down votes? I am just a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a function for formatting the response:

```
void printResult (int a, int b, int result, string op)
{
    std::cout<<"The result of "<<op<<" of "<<a<<" and "<<b<<" is: "<<result;
}
```

So you would have to modify every function like following:

```
void sum(int a, int b)
{
    int result = a + b;
    printResult(a, b, result, "sum")
}
```

```
void substract(int a, int b)
{
    int result = a - b;
    printResult(a, b, result, "substraction");
}
```

And so on...
So for the function printResult the parameters are the 2 numbers, the result and the operation which is a string.

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer! Keep up the good work!

Comment: Welcome bro! Thanks for answering my question!

Comment: I didnt get you. Revoke?

Comment: It was a bug where It stopped showing the green correct mark and it substracted the reputation points from my account but then it showed up again.

Comment: Ohh. No Problem. By the way Thanks again!